# No sound in headphones after moving to Ubuntu

Tags: sound, 18.04, asus, headphones

Today I just moved my PC ([Asus ROG GRB II](https://www.asus.com/us/Mini-PCs/ROG-GR8-II/)) to Ubuntu 18.04 from Win10. It doesn't have its own speakers, so I need to plug in headphones. Although I have 2 different ports (one for headphones, one for mic), in Win10 they always asked me what I wanted to connect (mic, loudspeakers, headphones, etc) in a small window, where I had to check the option "headphones" and click OK; then sound worked.

Ubuntu does not ask what I want to use for sound when I plug my headphones.I looked in pavucontrol output menu: on the first device - I suspect my headphones - I can see sound (orange label changing its length all the time).
Does someone know what's wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

So I opened pavucontrol and between two output devices (HDMI and stereo output) chose stereo output. Then I plugged headphones in the third port (on the other side of pc, don't know what it is for) and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try installing skype from snap instead of installing skypeforlinux

sudo apt-get remove skypeforlinux

sudo snap install --classic skype